# What happen if I use '#' in http post method in php?

Tags: php, http-post

Since `#` is deemed as a keyword for single line comment in php, what will happen if I use `#` as a variable of parameter for http post method? Below are example codes:

```php
$p = '#';
$x = $_POST{$p};
```

will the result be like

```php
$p = '#';
$x = $_POST#;
```

or will it be treated as an index of `$_POST`?

Comment: Execute it with proper PHP error reporting enabled, and you got your answer: _“Notice: Undefined index: # in […]”_

Comment: _...what will happen if I use..._ Try and find out! In case you don't have the required enviroment use sites like phptester.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a perfectly valid array key. A SUPERGLOBAL array is still an array.

Note, that old curly brace syntax will bonk in PHP7.4 and higher.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0BYAc))

```
$_POST['#'] = 'foo';

$p = '#';
echo $_POST{$p};
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($_POST);
```

Output:

```
foo
---
array (
  '#' => 'foo',
)
```